# Simple ImageMagick real world usable

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I've read the ImageMagick documentation [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) and [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/) and been unable to achieve a couple of simple tasks. Would appreciate any simple pointers or direction, or even commands I can execute that will work on Linux.

1. I want to convert any image-type (JPG, GIF, PNG, TIFF) to save to a PNG, losslessly, and as compressed as possible without any loss of quality. Ideally in 96 DPI so they look good in Retina screens.
2. To then take the above generated PNG and also resize it in specific sizes, with height and width specified.

What am I missing with the `convert` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert a TIF, GIF or JPEG to PNG, the command is:

```
convert image.tif result.png
```

or

```
convert image.jpg result.png
```

In answer to your questions...

**Question 1**

PNG is lossless by definition, so that is not an issue. To get better compression of a PNG, you generally need to reduce the colours, i.e.

```
convert image.jpg -colors 64 result.png   # or try 255 which allows a palettised image
```

The dpi is pretty irrelevant until you print on paper. More pixels are needed if you want more quality on screen.

**Question 2**

If you want to resize an image without destroying its aspect ratio, use

```
convert image.jpg -resize 200x100 result.png   # retain aspect ratio
```

If you don't care if that makes the image look stretched or distorted, and you want exactly 200x100, tell ImageMagick that you really mean it by shouting:

```
convert image.jpg -resize 200x100! result.png  # ignore aspect ratio
```

Comment: Often -colors 255 will work better than -colors 256 because, if the background color isn't one of the colors present in the palette, ImageMagick will add one more entry in the palette to hold it, ending up with 257 entries which it can't write as a palettised (indexed) PNG.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Thank you for pointing that out Glenn - I have edited it into the main text of the answer.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell. That's just what I was looking for.